Are tyres truly the best upgrade for a road bike to improve comfort and efficiency?
Im using a racing bike for commuting, the bike is more comfortable than I expected but since it is running narrow 22mm tyres I will see if things can be improved further by moving to 32mm.
Roads are poor here so 32mm may be faster on top of that.
I have often read that tyres are one of the most impactful things you can change on a roadbike...
Wondering if it would be worth investing in higher end tyres (e.g GP5000) over the budget options... as the price difference is not astronomical if those claims are true.
Can you expect a noticeable change from new tyres (of the same size) or is it more a case that with other bike upgrades (typically lightweight/aero parts) tend to give you a lot less bang for your buck?

Make sure you have enough frame clearance if you go to 32s

The answer to this question is wholly dependent on your goals. In your case it sounds like you're looking for comfort. But if you were looking to go faster, then sure, something aero might makes more sense.

Consider that between 22 and 32 are three other standard widths, 23mm and 25mm and 28mm.  No need to increase by 10mm.

sorry, what is GP?  GBP5000 (which i thought you meant given the speaking of "tyres") would seem to be more than i would ever expect to pay for bike tires...

@Michael: GP5000 most likely refers to Contintental Grand Prix 5000 road tyres. Which can be bought for around 45 euros a piece.

Great responses everyone, thanks.
@Criggie I did consider that, so assuming no fit issues, why wouldn't  you go for it?

I would improve tyres when you need to replace your tyres, not ditch new tyres for a different set of new tyres, to avoid throwing away money.

@Willeke agreed, that's what I normally do except when I relegate tyres to a less-good bike.  But I end up keeping any I do take off and there's only so much space available

My opinion is that there are three major features of a bike that can make a meaningful impact on how the bike feels when riding:

Tires
Pedals
Handlebars

I wouldn't exactly say that tires are always the best upgrade. For example, if you don't have clipless pedals but the tires are good and have low rolling resistance, the better upgrade would be to get clipless pedals than to continue micro-optimizing tire performance. Clipless pedals and shoes can be had for maybe $150-$200, two tires for maybe $100. But if the tires were already good, clipless pedals can give more bang for buck.
As for handlebars, if you already have a drop bar, changing to a different drop bar isn't that much different than just adjusting the handlebar height or stem length. But if you don't have a drop bar, then you have an upgrade path that's far more important than tires: getting a drop bar.
Unfortunately, conversion from a non drop bar bike to a drop bar bike isn't simple, it costs a lot of money, so in this case, although drop bar would give more bang than new tires, it costs so much that tires still give more bang for buck than swapping the handlebar.

My experience with 32mm GP5000 has been positive. They are some of the best tires you can have for riding on hard and hard-ish surfaces. The only caveat is that riding on construction gravel that consists of large sharp rocks ruins them in no time, since the sidewalls have no protecting rubber around them. A sidewall tear requires a tire boot, by the way (and subsequently a new tire since tire boot is not a permanent repair), simple inner tube patch isn't enough.
My experience with <32mm tires (specifically, 28mm tires) also has been that they are hard to pump up with a mini pump, so inflating roadside after a puncture is always annoying and leaves too little pressure in the tire even though your arms hurt from inflating the tire. I can't imagine how horrible 22mm tire inflation would be with a mini pump.

It has a drop bar and it's my first time using one.... indeed a big upgrade in many ways - comfort, speed, power, flexibility.
Thanks for info on GP5000, good to know

Tires are indeed among the upgrades that have the highest return. The website Bicycle Rolling Resistance performs measurements on key parameters for tires: rolling resistance, puncture resistance and wet grip. According to the website, there's factor 3 between the highest performing tires and the lowest on rolling resistance. Keep however in mind that rolling resistance and puncture resistance are generally antagonizing, so it may not be the best choice to take a race tire for a commuter if your commute is not on perfectly cleaned roads.
If you are after comfort, going for wider tires is the way to go if the frame allows it: wider tires can be run at lower pressure for the same rolling resistance (comparing here two different versions of the same tire family, provided that the two versions have the same structure). Bicycle Rolling Resistance has several articles on the topic.
If you are going for comfort, there are other upgrades that can work as well: compliant carbon seatposts (if your current one is aluminium and there's enough exposed seatpost, but the issue with carbon is that it's hard to know whether the post has been optimised for stiffness or compliance, gravel seatposts are generally optimised for compliance though), suspension seatposts (with a parallelogram, like Redshift/Canecreek, not the telescopic ones) or suspension stems.
If you want to improve aero, cycling clothing has probably a higher return on cost than any upgrade you can do an existing bike, as already pointed out. Aero bars can also provide big improvements for low money, but with serious compromises on bike handling and brake access, so are not generally not recommendable.

One should note though that rolling resistance becomes less and less important with speed; the factor 3 may translate into a few percent speed gain.

Aero bars are great at times, but the "for commuting" rules them out on most commutes.  It's rather disturbing seeing people using them on urban cycle routes.  As for tyres, those sold for training or off-season use for racers can be good in terms of wear and puncture protection, while only sacrificing a little speed (e.g.  Schwalbe One Plus - "Carefree road bike tire for training, commuting and urban areas")

If your frame came with 22mm tires, it is very unlikely that you have enough clearance for 32mm tires. The sort of road bikes that can take 32mm tires would have come with 28s stock. To find out how big tires you can fit, find the largest allen wrench you can put between the tire and the closest part of the frame or brake caliper, as shown here.
That said, tires are indeed a big upgrade, and going from a stock lower-end tire to a high-end one is a huge improvement. Be aware that the high-end tires don't necessarily have a tremendous lifespan. Anyway, that and either going to TPU tubes, latex tubes, or tubeless1 are probably the two most cost-effective upgrades you can make to the bike itself.
Once you have a bike, there isn't much aero upgrading you can do to the bike apart from the wheels and the handlebar. The latter may require re-doing the cables, which adds to the cost. You are likely better off upgrading your clothes and your position - learn the aero hoods position and build up so that you can hold it for a few minutes. And get tighter kit when it's time to get new kit.

Footnote

Do tubeless if and only if your rims are tubeless compatible. If they came with 22mm tires, it seems unlikely that these are from the tubeless era. However, latex and TPU tubes would still fit.


“the two most cost-effective upgrades you can make to the bike itself” The only downside is that you are upgrading wear parts.

@Michael I can't speak for road tires, but if I'm comparing the stock tires of the fun bike (gravel with small knobs, entry-level Bontrager ones) with mid-range or higher-end ones, I'm not sure that the TCO would be higher with the better tire. The compound was hard, wore out much faster than the other tires (I replaced them after one year, the tires that replaced them are still being used after more 3 years - I'm doing a rotation winter/summer). Of course there's some diminishing return if you go higher in ranges but starting from the low-end I have the impression there's no downside.

not all rims can do tubeless so it's not an option as an upgrade for a lot of bikes

@Vorsprung is correct, and also 23mm tires indicate an older bike and older rims.

@Renaud After several years of trying I still cannot noticeably war down the shitty Schwalbe Luganos to justify buying better ones. It is not my main bike, but still...

Ok, I misread my tyre size in low lighting, they are 25mm.
Still, the clearance to calipers is slightly under 4mm...
GP5000 measure slightly oversize at 28.5mm.
So seems there may not be enough clearance to size up even once.
Maybe the current tyre (Schwalbe Marathon,  some older variant I presume) are also a bit oversized, still a big gamble on the fit
